# R plot function not working ``Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ``

Tags: r

I am very new to R and now I am trying to plot a very simple normal distribution for mu = 179 and sigma = 9 but I am getting the following mistake  `Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :  'x' and 'y' lengths differ`
Here is my code

```
#Task 3.2 d) 
#Build graph both Normal distributions and see where they cross 
#For the Boys 
#Define Mu and Sigma
mu<-179
sigma<-9
#define a vector for the probability density function
probNorm<-vector(length = 1001)
seqCovered<-seq(0.5*mu, 1.5*mu, 0.01)
for(x in  1:1001) 
{
  probNorm[x]<-dnorm(seqCovered[x], mu, sigma)
}
plot(seqCovered, probNorm, main = paste("Normal Distribution for the boys with mu=", mu, "sigma=", sigma), ylim=c(0,1))
```

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: the error says exactly what is wrong, look at `length(seqCovered)` and `length(probNorm)`, try `seq(0.5*mu, 1.5*mu, length.out = 1001)` and also forget about the loop `dnorm(seqCovered, mu, sigma)`

Comment: Thanj you, now it works :)